# How can I find all the memory access addresses done via a load or store operations (ARM processor) with gdb or any other tool

Tags: memory, arm, gdb

I need to find the address of each memory location accessed by my program running on a Raspberyy pi3 based on ARMv7 ISA.

In essence i want to capture all the loads and stores of my program to build a detailed memory trace.  The final intention is to study how a particular memory access pattern affects the access latency and hence a detailed trace is important.

I tried tracing via gdb, like this:

```
gdb) while 1
> x/i $pc
>stepi
>end
```

However the problem is that it returns traces like

> ldr r3, [r7, #4]!

What i need is "ldr r3, Memory address" where i dont need to recompute the value stored in register r7 and add 4 and so on.

The program is fairly large and the trace took hours. Is there a way to get the addresses directly?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks much better

Comment: You are very welcome. I did make about 400 of such edits over the last weeks, and the number of people saying thank you ... is really really small.